# Add a header to a Word document?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to add a custom header to a .doc file using PowerShell (I mean the actual Header, not a heading). This SHOULD work:

```
$Word=New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$wdSeekPrimaryHeader = 1
$Doc=$Word.Documents.Open("C:\test.doc")
$Selection=$Word.Selection
$Doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView=$wdSeekPrimaryHeader
$Selection.TypeText("Text")
$doc.close([ref]$Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges)
$word.quit()
```

But it doesn't. It actually does nothing that I can tell.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the code that works:

```
$Word=New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$wdSeekPrimaryHeader = 1
$Doc=$Word.Documents.Open("C:\test.doc")
$Selection=$Word.Selection
$Doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView=$wdSeekPrimaryHeader
$Selection.TypeText("Text")
$Doc.Save()
$Doc.Close()
$Word.Quit()
```

Thanks again peeps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the [ref] works anyway but you've got it referencing DoNotSaveChanges. wouldn't you want save changes?

Comment: My bad, in the script I was trying this in, I had commented out the correct code, and was actually using the code I posted. Thanks for making me look more closely at that!

Comment: @JoeG no worries, (sadly) I'm all too familiar with making mistakes like that! I'll have a read around the [ref] as it's not something I've seen. Cheers, Matt

Comment: Glad things are working better, the [ref] is used in the case that the parameter is modified by the method or function that is being called.

Comment: @PeskyGnat Ah is it the same as ByRef in VB.Net then?

Answer (score 1):

I get an error on the [ref] (Argument: '1' should not be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Do not use [ref].)
If I replace the close(..) line with:

```
$doc.save()
$doc.close()
```

Then I see the header

Comment: What version of Word do you have installed?

Comment: $word.Version prints out '12.0'