# Insert a Header in word via powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I am trying the powershell script from this [Microsoft Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/02/18/use-powershell-to-add-headers-to-word-documents/)

```
$EmptyDoc = Get-ChildItem 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\test_folder\\empty.docx' $Path -Recurse -Include *.docx
$wdApplication = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$wdApplication.visible = $true
$wdDocumentPath = $EmptyDoc.FullName

write $wdDocumentOpenPath

$wdDocument = $wdApplication.Documents.Open($wdDocumentPath)

$section = $wdDocument.sections.item(1)
$header = $section.headers.item([microsoft.office.interop.word.WdHeaderFooterIndex]::wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)

$header.range.InsertAlignmentTab([microsoft.office.interop.word.WdAlignmentTabAlignment]::wdLeft)
$header.range.InsertAfter("Test Header")

$wdDocument.Save()
$wdDocument.Close()
$wdApplication.quit()
exit
```

I am running it on an empty word .docx file [wdFormatXMLDocument]. However, after running the script, the .docx is still an empty file. I have tried going through **MSDN documentations** for `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and my function calls seem to be right.

Comment: Maybe try this [Add a header to a Word document?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6221783)

Comment: If you comment out the Close and Quit lines so that the document is left open: 1) Do you see anything? 2) Are you able to type something into the header as an end-user? As far as the object model goes, your code looks fine (I know the object model, but don't use PowerShell).

Comment: @CindyMeister when I run the code without the close and quit, I'm still on top of my docx file in the body and no access to the header.

Comment: @JamesC. Thank you for the link, it works just fine for me. I did want to know why my format did not work, but guess I will settle for the other format. If you want to post it as a solution I will upvote it for you.

Comment: If you have no access to the header then something is wrong. Is it possible some kind of protection has been applied to the document? If you look in the Developer tab's "Restrict Editing" pane does that show "Stop protection" or "Yes, Start enforcing protection"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a header to a Word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221783/add-a-header-to-a-word-document)

Comment: @CindyMeister yes the link you sent works fine on my Doc file and outputs a header, all I wanted to know was why my current does not work. It seems as you have said some access restrictions.